# Which browsers already support Media Queries Level 4?

Tags: css

Which browsers already support some of these attributes?
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries4/

This one f.e. does not work on iOS7, iPhone 4S

```
@media (luminosity: normal) {
    body {
        background: #f5f5f5;
        color: #262626;
    }
}

@media (luminosity: dim) {
    body {
        background: #e9e4e3;
    }
}

@media (luminosity: washed) {
    body {
        background: #ffffff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Luminosity works on iOS7 and Android 4.

Comment: OP, @Pinal; clearly it would be better to post what you want, then to link  an entire document and get upset when users dont read through everything. Its obvious that this question could be improved any sort of specifics.

Comment: Luminosity seems not to work on iOS7 (iPhone 4S)

Answer (score 2):

Here, on [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=media), you can find updated and current support for many CSS properties. In this specific case, some of Level 4 Media are already supported even if in not standard way, such as:

1. "*API for finding out whether or not a media query applies to the document*"
2. "*Method of accessing external device data (such as a webcam video stream)*"

Comment: the new level 4 syntax options are pretty specific and a general "sort of supported sometimes" doesn't really go far enough to answer the question

Comment: we're in 2020 and `caniuse` is missing `css4 media queries` — there is `css3 media queries` but that's a decade-old spec, no surprises

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE 2022 JULY:

Chrome started supporting this feature from chrome version 104 but still Chrome for android and Safari for both iPhone and mac lacks the support.(No need to worry about IE since it support ended by Microsoft)

---

Now it's working at least on Firefox.
so now you can write media queries like following:

```
@media (width <= 30em) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

no i think you cant because of the common unsupportable browsers such as firefox and opra as well as IE*!
this is some resources about it
[Feature: Media Queries: interaction media features](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction)

Comment: imho, I suggest to provide an answer in a form that fits the question. i.e.: Q: Who does speak German? A: Marco and Clara do. Also.. pay more attention to typos. I also suggest to provide an extract or a more complete summary of the external linked page. This makes your answer, self-consistent in the case the linked page disappears. About the answer, Edge is the currently usoft reference browser, and it looks that Firefox is the only big one lacking support.

Comment: imho you may improve your answer following my tips imho

Answer (score 0):

PPK is generating some [media queries support tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/mediaqueries/) and has [tests you can use yourself](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tests/mediaqueries/luminosity.html) too.

The spec is still a draft, maybe try mobile Firefox as that has support for some luminocity via javascript.

Comment: Just tested on my iOS7 iPhone 4 - not supported on either Safari or Chrome (which sits on Safari so not surprising)

Answer (score 0):

MDN has [per feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) support tables for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). That seems to be the best option for this information.